# Force reload of style.css in WooCommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to force a style.css reload for users, as their browser cache might mess up the design. I am trying to work with a version to it (f.e. `style.css?ver=2`).

Is that the best way to do it? Eventually I might look into running this dynamic as shown on [link](https://www.launch2success.com/guide/force-css-changes-to-go-live-immediately-in-wordpress/). But right now I cannot even get this to work.

I am using Salient Theme, and they have an enqueue.php script which loads the .css files if I am correct. For now, I have added the `?ver=2` to the code below. However, this still now changes the output when I look at my homepage. I have cleared cached and double checked whether query-strings are allowed. But server caching and WP-rocket seem to allow this. Any pointers on how I can get this working to force the style.css reload?

```php
if( is_child_theme() ) {
    $nectar_theme_version = nectar_get_theme_version();
    wp_register_style( 'salient-child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css?ver=2', '', $nectar_theme_version );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'salient-child-style' );
}
```

**UDPATE:** 
I have tried changing that code to `/style2.css`. That does seem to update the output. So seems I am in the right settings, but the query is being cut off.

Answer (score 1):

I would programmatically version it using `filemtime`. Even if the version is not showing, the browser *should* be reading the new file:

```
if( is_child_theme() ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 
            'salient-child-style', 
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', 
            [], 
            filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css' )
        );
    }
```

Basically, this will get the file's modified time and if it's different, the version will update and let the browser know the version changed. Also you really don't need a separate `wp_register_style`, but if you want to keep it:

```
if( is_child_theme() ) {
        $nectar_theme_version = nectar_get_theme_version();
        wp_register_style( 'salient-child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', '', filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css' ) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'salient-child-style' );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put these meta tags in your header.php file (inside head tag):

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to give version to your styles after each update!

```
style.css?ver=1.0

style.css?ver=2.0

style.css?ver=3.0
```